# Set virtualenv interpreter to run as root?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, root, pyenv

I'm using PyCharm to remotely execute a project on a RPi via SSH interpreter.  The target for the interpreter is `pyenv` virtualenv built specifically for the project; i.e. the project requires `libbluetooth` so that `socket` is built with `AF_BLUETOOTH` support.

Everything works as expected except for one aspect: the interpreter needs to run as root because some of the HCI commands (communication with the bluetooth controller) needs root privileges; otherwise, `socket.send(...)` will raise `PermissionError`.

I was reading [Run/Debug as root in PyCharm](https://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/), but I was wondering if it is possible to setup the active pyenv interpreter to automatically execute  with root privileges?

Comment: Have you tried the blog post's advice, i.e. adding `<user> <host> = (root) NOPASSWD: <full/path/to/pyenv/python>` to sudoers (`/etc/sudoers.d/python`) on the RPi?

Comment: @Andrew yes, I followed the instructions with small difference: I put the python-sudo.sh in the `bin` directory of the virtual environment. The problem is that setting the script as the target for the interpreter causes the python console in pycharm to crash when opening; however, running scripts and tests works fine